# C# 2 Methods of Bubble Sort (Performance)

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

can anyone explain this to me?

I have written 2 bubble-sort methods, which differ only in one variable declaration.
I excepted, that Method 1 would be faster.

Here the stopWatch results:

- Method 1 (without a extra variable declaration):

  - First Try: Seconds: 3 MilliSeconds: 8
  - Second Try: Seconds: 3 MilliSeconds: 842
  - Third Try: Seconds: 3 MilliSeconds: 870
- Method 2  (with a extra variable declaration):

  - First Try: Seconds: 2 MilliSeconds: 522
  - Second Try: Seconds: 3 MilliSeconds: 121
  - Third Try: Seconds: 2 MilliSeconds: 899

Both sorted an array with a length of 10000.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var intArray = RandomIntArrayGenerator();

        Method1(intArray.ToArray());
        Method2(intArray.ToArray());
    }

    private static int[] RandomIntArrayGenerator()
    {
        int[] iArray = new int[10000];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            iArray[i] = random.Next(1, 100001);
        }

        return iArray;
    }

    private static void BubbleSort(int[] intArray)
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        var sortNotFinished = true;

        stopWatch.Start();
        while (sortNotFinished)
        {
            var sortList = new List<bool>();

            for (var i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 1 < intArray.Length)
                {
                    if (intArray[i] > intArray[i + 1])
                    {
                        //Method 1 start:
                        var a = intArray[i];

                        intArray[i] = intArray[i + 1];
                        intArray[i + 1] = a;
                        //Method 1 end:


                        //Method 2 start:
                        var a = intArray[i];
                        var b = intArray[i + 1];

                        intArray[i] = b;
                        intArray[i + 1] = a; 
                        //Method 2 end:

                        sortList.Add(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sortList.Add(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            sortNotFinished = sortList.Any(item => item == false);
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
  }
```

Why is a extra variable declaration faster?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Try calling `Method2` before `Method1` in your `Main`.

Comment: @GuruStron tried it, the same result, the one with the extra var declaration is faster

Comment: It's doubtful that you'll learn anything useful from this exercise. There aren't universal truths to learn when it comes to writing useful code. *if* you have code *where* performance matters you need to measure useful workloads in that area and decide for yourself what works well.

Comment: The difference is negligible. Try 100000 numbers 100 times with both, and the same input and get the mean execution time. Even this will not be definite as performance is not easily measured with such minor differences.

Comment: On my machine the second version also consistently runs a little faster (less than 20% difference each time).  You might be able to get a better idea of why by looking at the IL that's generated from your code.  The extra variable declaration may be optimized away, and there could be other differences.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters that this is unlikely to provide useful learnings when it comes to optimizing the performance of real-world code.  But I don't think there's anything wrong with being curious about it, and it could be a chance to learn a bit about the kinds of transformations the C# compiler performs.

Comment: @TimGoodman where can I look at the IL? 

Yeah, I program these examples just to get an little insight into algorithms and how they work :)

Comment: You can use https://sharplab.io/, ILSpy or DnSpy to see the generated IL

Comment: @Slugart thank you!